# Ssl pinning using Alamofire not blocking requests in other domain

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, alamofire

I am working on an iOS project that uses `Alamofire`. I am trying to implement ssl pinning. I have bundled the der file in my app. Here is my code

```
class ApiSessionnManager{

    static let shared = ApiSessionnManager()
    var afmanager:SessionManager

    init(){

        let domain = "herokuap.com"
        let githubCert = "herokuapp" // Dev ssl cert and Prod ssl cert ****

        let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: githubCert, ofType: "der")

        let localCertificate: Data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToCert!))

        let localCertificateCfData: CFData = localCertificate as CFData

        let secCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificateCfData)!

        let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(certificates: [secCert], validateCertificateChain: true, validateHost: true)

        let serverTrustPolicies = [

            domain: serverTrustPolicy

        ]
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

            configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

            self.afmanager =  SessionManager(configuration: configuration,serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))




    }



}
```

In my Viewcontroller class i have

```
func signIn()   {
        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "id" : "user" as AnyObject,
            "password" : "pass" as AnyObject

        ]

        ApiSessionnManager.shared.afmanager.request("https://floating-stream-25740.herokuapp.com/authentication/login", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
        }
```

I am getting a success response. But the problem is even if i change the domain I am still getting the success response. Ssl not blocking the requests from other domain.
Any help will be appreciated.